# Execute geocodeAddressString twice (Calculating distance between two CLLocations) - Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, core-location, cllocation

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two addresses. This shouldn't be a problem, but I have problems converting the address to CLLocations. The first time geocodeAddressString is called, everything works, but in fact it is not called a second time. I set a breakpoint, nothing happened. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

```
lazy var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
var plz1 = "45345"
var plz2 = "22927"

weak var Ort1: CLLocation?
weak var Ort2: CLLocation?

    func calcDistance(){
        let address1 = "\("Germany"), \(plz1)"
        let address2 = "\("Germany"), \(plz2)"

        getLocation(address: address1)
        getLocation(address: address2)

        //print(Ort1?.distance(from: Ort2!))
    }

    func getLocation(address: String) {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil){
                print("Error", error ?? "")
            }
            if (placemarks?.first) != nil {
                var location: CLLocation?
                location = placemarks?.first?.location
                self.Ort1 = location
                let coordinate = location?.coordinate
                print(coordinate!.latitude)
                print(coordinate!.longitude)
                self.geocoder.cancelGeocode()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: This code is invalid, it is not using the completionHandler for getLocation and why are you using variable placeholder for static text? `"\("Germany"),` just use `"Germany, \(plz1)"`

Comment: That is strange that's it's not called the second time, but you clearly don't manage the fact that `geocodeAddressString()` is async. The fact that you call an `cancelGeocode()` might cause issue?